# Megamenu Design Positioning Issue Only CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, megamenu

I am Using React whether I Required to design a Custom Megamenu but the issue is, it is inside An Wrapper of Unordered List and it is taking the relative position of any List Item.

[image]

Here "Shop By Category" is A Div and the Links As Unordered List's List Item is Wrapped into a Wrapper of "Shop By Category" And the Megamenu is again a Div.

My Exact Requirement is :

[image]
Whether on Any link it Hovers Megamenu want to take initial position of the Wrapper.